# How to access application properties from controller/service with jhipster?

Tags: jhipster

Into my application.yml there is a property : eureka.instance.appname

How can i access it from my Rest Controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the parameters of you controller method you can add

`@Value("${eureka.instance.appname}") String eurekaName`

which you can use further.